# How can I get the text in QTableWidgetItem

Tags: pyqt4

I create a QWizard page, in the page, there is a QTableWidge include 4 rows and 6 cols, in each cell, I create a QTableWidge contains 2 rows and 1 col, we can input text to these small cells. Now I want to get all changed text before go to next page. What can I do? Thanks.

can not upload picture......

Answer (score 0):

Use signals/slots to create a method that is run on when the following signal is emitted:
    void QTableWidget::itemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem * item ) [signal]

with connect: 
    connect(tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(on_table_item_changed(QTableWidgetItem*)));

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: for row, col in cellDict:
         cellTableWidget = TrayTable(row, col, cellDict[(row, col)])
         cellTableWidget.connect(cellTableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemSelectionChanged()'), self.onSelection)
         self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row-1, col-1, cellTableWidget)
         self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(row-1,   CELL_HEIGHT)
         self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(col-1, CELL_WIDTH)  in TrayTable I create small tableWidget with 2 rows 1 col. so the signal is connected to self.tableWidget or cellTableWidget?

Comment: or can I check through cells at validatePage()?

Comment: It's a little hard to see what's going on with your code in the comment but I believe self.tableWidget (in this context) are the table widgets embedded in the larger TableWidget correct? If so you probably want to use the signal emitted by the embedded table widgets if possible. If you have issues that way you may be able to use the signal emitted by the larger tablewidget item that should be emitted when the embedded tablewidgets are changed.

Comment: Yes, you could use "QTableWidgetItem * itemAt ( int ax, int ay ) const" for each of the embedded tables cells when you do validatePage() and check for changes.  Though if you can get the signal/slot method working that would probably be best.

Comment: so if I check the changes in validatePage(), I think don't need any signal. right? But I don't know how to coding to get text in small TableWidget item. I will upload picture once I can

Comment: Can you use ItemAt on the large table widget for each position, which would return a pointer to the small table widget. Then use ItemAt on the small table widget for each position to get their content?

Comment: self.tableWidget.cellWidget(0,3).item(0,0).text() this line can get content. Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks a lot but answer unnaccepted? kinda strange, 4 years later? is this a bug or is this for real?  I provided an accepted answer now stack overflow just goes "nope" and takes it back 4 years later, I highly doubt the user did it, unless they are super weird. (which i highly doubt, like I said)